# Replacing Standard Errors in a Reg Model in R

Tags: r, regression, standard-error

I am in search of a way to directly replace the standard errors in a regression model with my own standard errors in order to use the robust model in another R package that does not come with its own robust option and can only be fed particular types of models and not coeftest formats.

Let's say I have a linear model:

```
model <- lm(data=dat, Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3)
```

I then want robust standard errors:

```
robust <- coeftest(model, vcov=sandwich)
```

Next, I need to use this model in a specific package that cannot be fed a coeftest and does not have its own robust standard errors option. I would like to replace the original model's standard errors (and, for that matter, p-values, t-statistics, etc.) prior to feeding it into the package so that they are accounted for.

To access the standard errors in the *original model*, I use:

```
summary(model)$coefficients[,2]
```

To extract the standard errors from the *coeftest*, I use:

```
coeftest.se <- robust[, 2]
```

The following method, however, returns an error when trying to replace the model's standard errors because it is treating "summary" itself as a command:

```
summary(model)$coefficients[,2] <- coeftest.se


Error in summary(M3)$coefficients[, 2] <- seM3 : could not find function "summary<-"
```

**The Specifics**

I am trying to run mediation analysis with the Mediation R package. The package will do one way clustered standard errors with the "mediate" function, but I would like two way clustered standard errors.

To get two way clustered standard errors, I am using Mahmood Arai's mclx function (code can be found [here](http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.216115.1426234213!/menu/standard/file/clustering1.pdf) (p. 4).

My idea is to feed the package's mediate function with models that already report the correct standard errors. According the documentation, the mediation package accepts the following classes of models: lm, polr, bayespolr, glm, bayesglm, gam, rq, survreg, and merMod.

Comment: So, `summary(model)` is a function of the model, not a part of the model. The standard errors *aren't* part of the model, the summary function calculates them on the fly (see `summary.lm` to see how).

Comment: So the easiest solution is probably to modify your "specific package" to use robust standard errors, or maybe it could be fed an `rlm` object. Either way, can't help much without knowing what you're trying to use this in.

Comment: It really depends on the function you'd be massing the model to. The `lm` object is a "living" object. It knows the data used to fit it and the original call. Modifying it's internal properties isn't guaranteed to result in the behavior you want. you really should provide a more complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that shows what you are trying to do with the model down stream.

Comment: I have included some specific details. I was mostly thinking about this from a theoretical perspective, but I'd be happy to include a reproducible example soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
    model <- lm(data=dat, Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3)

    library(sandwich)

    SE_robust <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type="HC2")))

    model2 <- summary(model)

    model2$coefficients[,2] <- SE_robust
```

Answer (score 1):

@MySeppo's answer is great, but I think it is worth giving a function here that changes everything to be robust (SEs, t-stats, p-values) for more generality (I'm also using HC1 to be consistent with Stata):

```
model <- lm(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars)

robustsummary <- function(model) { 
  library(sandwich)
  library(lmtest)
  coeftest <- coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type="HC1"))
  summ <- summary(model)
  summ$coefficients[,2] <- coeftest[,2]
  summ$coefficients[,3] <- coeftest[,3]
  summ$coefficients[,4] <- coeftest[,4]
  summ
}
summary(model)
robustsummary(model)
```

Or if you don't want to use `coeftest`

```
robustsummary <- function(model) { 
  library(sandwich)
  SE_robust <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type="HC1")))
  summ <- summary(model)
  summ$coefficients[,2] <- SE_robust
  summ$coefficients[,3] <- summ$coefficients[,1]/SE_robust # get t-stats
  summ$coefficients[,4] <- 2*(1-pt(abs(summ$coefficients[,3]),summ$df[2])) # apply t distribution with the right degrees of freedom to get p-values
  summ
}
```

Comment: Hi @Richard DiSalvo, Your solution to get a robust summary is perfect! Thanks. However, is it possible to have the values adjusted within the "model"? so that when I run the summary(model), I get a robust summary? I ask this because I want to feed the model further to predict values and calculate inverse mills ratio. Could you please guide me? Appreciate it.

Comment: @fsure I don't think that is possible, since I think summary() or coeftest() uses the model to calculate the standard errors. Robust standard errors just uses a different formula than summary() uses by default. However, I don't think robust standard errors will affect predicted values from a model. But it would affect confidence intervals for conditional means, and prediction intervals. I'm less sure about the inverse mills ratio. I would look into the functions you are feeding the model into and see if they have a way to say to use robust (or likely more importantly, clustered) SE formulas.